# MongoDB Comapss throws error Server at 127.0.0.1:27017 reports wire version 0

Tags: mongodb, compass

I'm getting this error message when trying to connect to my local mongodb via MonogoDB Compass:

> Server at 127.0.0.1:27017 reports wire version 0, but this version of
>   Node.js Driver requires at least 2 (MongoDB2.6).

I can easily connect to the db using mongo.exe console application.

MongoDB Compass version 1.12.4
Monogo version 2.4.9

Comment: Your compass version is latest while Mongo version is old, upgrade and it should be ok.

Comment: You are right. that was the problem.
Thanks!